# JPA: how to avoid timeout issue for EAGER fetching

Tags: jpa, fetch, openjpa

I am facing a situation in JPA.

I have an entity,say A.A has parent-child relationship with itself.So A can have a collection of A(children) and and an A(parent).If parent is null, it means A is root node of the hierarchy.

My use case is such that I need to fetch all data in table(which can be around 30k-40k rows) and then organize it in tree structures as per parent-child relationship between the entities.

So I decided to have EAGER fetching for Collection field, so JPA would itself fetch data in the required tree structure, and it works very fine.
But in other use cases fetching entire data of A is not needed, and also it causes timeout issue when there is too much data.
So how can I work around this issue?

I plan to have two entities mapped to the table,one having EAGER strategy while other having LAZY strategy. So I would use EAGER one in my use case and other use cases would use LAZY one.
Would this be a clean solution?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so. I never tried attaching two separate entities to the same table for any reason, and it *feels* like a problematic idea. Rather, I would suggest you either look into setting the query timeout, which seems like a bad idea because you are going to get a lot of data you said you don't need, and obviously your performance is going to be bad.

Or, and probably the best solution, stop the eager fetch where it is not always a requirement, I think you said in Entity A. Since A is essentially a Node in a Tree structure, putting Fetch=EAGER is always going to fetch the entire tree, which, as you say, can be quite large. Large enough to be causing problems in some cases. I would recommend removing the EAGER fetch, building a few named queries, and managing what you fetch through the service layer. It's not very hard and has worked quite well in the past for me.

Comment: I removed the EAGER fetch. Now I am activating EAGER fetch during run time using FETCH MODE. It seems to work fine so far.